# Does CDI offer an api for a default producer?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, guice, cdi

I have a bunch of dependencies written as fast binary web services (aka Ejb3.1). Here is the service delcaration:

```
@Remote
public interface MyService {...}
```

You would inject an EJB into a servlet or managed bean with the following syntax:

```
@EJB
MyService myService;
```

I don't want to use the `@EJB` injection however. I'd like to use plain vanilla CDI:

```
@Inject
MyService myService;
```

One way to accomplish this would be to Create a `@Produces` method for every EJB:

```
@Produces MyService produceMyService(InjectionPoint ijp){
 //jndi lookup for MyService interface
}
```

However, InjectionPoint is capable of giving you all the information you need, such as the target class name (MyService in this case).

Is there a way in CDI to do something like this? I'd want to call this producer last, if the required injection point couldn't be fulfilled in any other manner.

```
@Produces Object produce(InjectionPoint ijp){
 Class ejbInterface = ijp.getType();
 //jndi lookup for ejbInterface
}
```

This is a confusing post, so ask clarification questions. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yes, quite confusing indeed :) Did I understand you correctly that you are looking for a way to resolve dependencies in a kind of "local first, remote only if local failed"-way?

Comment: yes, that'd be great. Basically a "catch all" for dependencies that couldn't be injected any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that I understood your question (see comment): No, there is no API for this.

Good news is that there is a way to achieve this - but you probably don't want to do this at runtime, that's rather a task for application startup.

The [CDI extension mechanism](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html) offers you some well defined hooks into bean processing at **container startup**. This is a perfect place for logic that decides about enabling / disabling of certain managed beans (probably based on static classpath information).

Have a look at function and implementation of Seam [Solder](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/solder-programmingmodel.html#d0e384)'s `@Requires`. That should be pretty close to your use case...